# How to verify the added data in table through assert - Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium webdriver and came against an issue. I have a function that adds a particular event (with date and event name) in a table. Now i want to verify in my test through an assert function whether my event is added or not based on event date. The number of events in the table are not fixed, so every time I add an event, the number will change.

This is my code to add event in the table.

```
public void addIndividualEvent(String eventDate, String eventName) throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(individualEventDate).sendKeys(eventDate);
        driver.findElement(individualEventName).sendKeys(eventName);
        driver.findElement(addIndividualEventBtn).click();
    }
```

Now when this test run in my suite, I dont know how many events are already there in the table. So, I manually added ONLY 2 events and applied the for loop on those 2 events like this:

```
public void individualEventVerify()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

            String sRowValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='event-analysis-form']/div/study-event-series/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).getText();
            System.out.println(sRowValue);
        }
    }
```

This prints out 2 event dates correctly. 
From here, how can I assert/verify if my date is there or not?

Comment: I don't understand your question. individualEventVerify prints out the data you inserted with addIndividualEvent then isn't that proof that your date was correctly inserted?

Comment: Yes, but how can I utilize this as my assertion?

Comment: make indivudalEventVerify a boolean and pass the boolean to an assert

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `Assert.assertEquals` function like so:

```
Assert.assertEquals(sRowValue, "XX/XX/XX");
```

It will fail the test if the `sRowValue` does not equal "XX/XX/XX" or whatever date you have included.